# My javascript works in every browser but IE8

Tags: javascript, html, json, internet-explorer-8

By every browser, I mean Safari, Firefox, Chrome, and IE9.

Here is the error I'm getting in IE8's console:

`'data.cities[...].country' is null or not an object`

Line 374, which is below (`var country = k.data.cities[i].country;`):

```
downloadUrl(url, function(data) {
    var k = eval("(" + data.responseText + ")"); 
    var klength = k.data.cities.length;
    var countries = [];

    for(i=0; i < klength; i++) {
        var country = k.data.cities[i].country;
        countries.push(country);
    }

    countries = $.unique(countries);

    var countryLength = countries.length;

    for(i=0; i < countryLength; i++) {
        $('.ribbon').append('<a href="#" class="country '+ countries[i] +'">' + countries[i] + '</a>');
    }
});
```

Why would IE8 be the only browser having a problem with this line? I know the data being fed is not null, as the same data is used to place objects on a map and they display just fine.

Comment: It seems that it thinks the `k` variable is `null`, which tells me that there is something wonky with the `var k = eval("(" + data.responseText + ")");` line.  What is the purpose of the parentheses concatenated with `data.responseText`?  Have you tried just `eval(data.responseText)`?

Comment: Try to omit the last comma within `data.responseText`.

Comment: just a tip: take "var country;" out of the loop, and remove "var" from the loop. no need to re-declare in each iteration, since it exists outside the scope of the for() loop

Comment: I suspect the same as @nalply . The following example: `{a: 1, b: 2,}` is not a syntactically corect JS object. However, every browser except IE parses it the way you would expect them. If you're dealing with JSON, this is the most probable cause of your problem.

Comment: By the way, using `eval()` is seriously bad practice. After having fixed your endpoint you should switch to `JSON.parse()`, which is also supported by IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the eval() function doesn't return what you expect.

You might want to try using JSON.parse instead.

You can find a parser [there](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for browsers that don't have native support for JSON.

Comment: You can also use `data = $.parseJSON(data)` right after `...function(data) {...` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most probably that `data.responseText` might have a trailing comma somewhere.

```
[
    "A", "B", "C",
]
```

This does not work for Internet Explorer and is also not valid JSON. All other browsers cope with the trailing comma.

Fix: Change your AJAX end point to omit all trailing commas.

Even better fix: Use `JSON.parse` which will bomb for non-valid JSON, so that all browser behave the same by failing.

Comment: I'm thinking this may be the problem, as, low and behold, I have a trailing comma in my data.txt file. I've submitted the revision and am crossing my fingers.